# What is this identifier in my ubuntu terminal?

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu, terminal, terminator

I recently got my office machine whith Ubuntu 16.04 and created a new account on it since my machine belonged to a previous employee. My machine has Terminator as default terminal emulator. However, in the account of the previous employee, his terminator and terminal both have a fancy identifier of sorts which can tell you the branch you're on git.

What is this? How can i install it on my Terminator? (the blue and yellow arrow)

Here's how it looks on Terminator

[image: Terminator]

Here's how it look on Terminal

[image: Terminal]

Comment: https://github.com/banga/powerline-shell?

Comment: Isn't this some zsh feature?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the [agnoster](https://github.com/agnoster/agnoster-zsh-theme) zsh theme, probably with [Solarized Dark](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color scheme.

[image]

More themes can be found [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes).

If you'd like to know *exactly* what kind of theme it is and what plugins are used, take a look at the `~/.zshrc` file. There you should find a line that looks something like `ZSH_THEME="agnoster"`. More info can be found on [Oh My ZSH](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) Github.

Comment: how do i install it? doesn't show any information regarding installation on their git

Comment: @rizvified, or does it? [This](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Installing-ZSH) is how you install ZSH, and the instructions for Oh My ZSH installation are right in front of you when you follow the last link in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It all worked!

Comment: @rizvified, you're welcome! Also, for the future, please note that there's a whole SE site dedicated to Ubuntu: [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour).

Comment: Noted. Thanks a bunch!